# Driving a Novation UltraNova synth via a Yahama synth guitar (G10 ?)

Tags: guitar, synthesizer, midi

Would it be possible to play on a Yahama syntheziser guitar, and get the sounds and instruments to actually come out of the sound bank of the Novation UltraNovation synthesizer ?

(please feel free to add HTTP links to the relevant pics / instrument websites to enrich this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UltraNovation can be set up to trigger on the MIDI input as well as, or instead of the keyboard so you can assign any patches you like to the G10 as a trigger.

The G10 is designed this way, so any MIDI synth can provide the sound - the advantage is that you can do all the usual things you would do on a guitar - whammy, string bends etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what guitar controllers with MIDI are for. You just connect one to the other with a MIDI cable.