# Would it be possible to use the sounds stored in a Novation UltraNova by plugging a Yahama V50 to it?

Tags: synthesizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Driving a Novation UltraNova synth via a Yahama synth guitar (G10 ?)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/driving-a-novation-ultranova-synth-via-a-yahama-synth-guitar-g10)

So I have this one :

http://www.vintagesynth.com/yamaha/v50.php

and that one :

http://us.novationmusic.com/hardware-synths/ultranova/

How could I plug the Yamaha (which has more keys !) to the Novation (which has a bewildering, stupendous, ear pleasing sounds!) together in order to produce awesome atmospheric tunes ?

Comment: @WheatWilliams: Indeed. I may have just edited the first question. Entschuldigung !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer you to my answer on [Using keyboard/MIDI controller to learn piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/using-keyboard-midi-controller-to-learn-piano)

Both of your instruments contain a "MIDI controller".

Both of your instruments contain a "MIDI sound module".

Any MIDI controller can control any MIDI sound module.

Answer (score 2):

You use a MIDI cable, just like you would use to connect any piece of MIDI gear to any other piece of MIDI gear. Skippy, you are asking the exact same question you [already asked here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/driving-a-novation-ultranova-synth-via-a-yahama-synth-guitar-g10) just a couple of days ago.

### MIDI

Here's an extensive explanation for German speakers: [Was ist MIDI?](http://www.musica.at/midi/) **Grundlegendes zum Thema MIDI und Audio**

Google "What is MIDI?" in English, and I'm sure you'll find equally useful information.

Comment: I'm not sure how a question about a Yamaha V50 can be a duplicate of a question regarding a Yahama G10.

Comment: It's a duplicate because the answer to both questions is "plug in a MIDI cable".

Comment: Most here don't read German.

Comment: Skippy, the asker of the question, is Austrian, and I suspect his problem is that he doesn't fully understand our explanations in English, so I thought I'd give him an explanation in German. Is there a prohibition against using anything other than English on StackExchange?

Comment: No, I didn't realize he was spoke German.  Do you?

Comment: Skippy's profile says he lives in Vienna. And yes: English is my first language, but I speak German and have a working knowledge of French and Spanish.

Comment: @WheatWilliams: many thanks for the attention of providing me with a German language answer. It is much appreciated.